# Text Scaling seems to have no effect

Tags: android

```
    private fun setQuestion() {
        val mainImg = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.movieImgView)
        val movieNameText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.movieName)
        val movieYearText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.movieYear)
        val movieRatingText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.movieRatingText)
        val seriesOrNoText = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.seriesOrNoText)
        val btnNext = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnNext)

        movieList = Constants.getActionMovies()
        val movie: ActionMovies? = movieList!![currentPosition - 1]

        val displayMetrics = DisplayMetrics()
        windowManager.defaultDisplay.getMetrics(displayMetrics)
        val height = displayMetrics.heightPixels.toFloat()
        val width = displayMetrics.widthPixels.toFloat()

        mainImg.setImageResource(movie!!.moviePic)

        movieNameText.text = movie.movieName
        movieNameText.scaleX = width
        movieNameText.scaleY = height

        movieYearText.text = "(${movie.date.toString()})"
        movieRatingText.text = movie.rating

        if (movie.series) {
            seriesOrNoText.text = "Yes"
        } else {
            seriesOrNoText.text = "No"
        }

        if (currentPosition == movieList!!.size) {
            btnNext.text = "Return to \n Main Menu"
            btnNext.setOnClickListener {
                finish()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to set the width and height of my `MovieNameText`, however it seems to have no effect at all, any help? I've defined the text size in the xml file to 30sp, I've tried `setText` and `scaleX` and `textSize`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To change the size of the text

```
movieNameText.textSize = 30f // or whatever value you would like to use
```

Aslong as your Textview is constrained and layout width and height is set to 'wrap content' it should scale with your app.